# react-native error RCTPushNotification I need be membership of apple to use Local PushNotificationiOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I'm trying to implement iOS push notification for react-native 
I have tried several ways to implement RCTPushNotification, no effective success via link and manually.

Can I enable PushNotification on Capabilities using a personal account or add to react in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this article : [rn-ios-push notification](https://hackernoon.com/complete-guide-receive-push-notifications-in-react-native-ios-app-38b1ec5b1b15) . It explains how to integrate push notification in ios react native app. And for actually implemnting it in server side you need certificates hence its mandatory to be enrolled in apple developer program .

> Requirement: You should have a valid Apple Developer Program Membership (100$/year).

Hopeit helps. feel free for doubts